# String manipulation , at a complete loss

Tags: c++

I am trying to grab sub-strings out of a larger string and I have got it to work in a small program but when I try to run it into the real program it just goes wrong. I am building off someone else s function and got it to work for my purpose, but cannot get it to work in the main program I need it in. I will limit the program down to where I think error is occurring.

Problem: I pass in same value into function findStats(std::string sString) but get different results.
Case I:

```
stats = findStats("^9dff9d[Attribute 0% Active Defense 0]\r^f2f3f2Mana: 1411 ^00ff00(+1975)\r^f2f3f2^9dff9d[Attribute 0% Active Mana 0]\r^f2f3f2^ffc000Fortify Level: 12/12\r^f2f3f2^006effIdentified Attribute: + 6% Crit Damage\rIdentified Attribute: + 6  Accuracy\r^f2f3f2^006eff^O053Sacrifice Elapse(6/8)\r^00ff00  ^O041Desollar's Shadow\rÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌL«");
```

The above case will output correctly and stores \r offsets correctly.

Case II:

```
stats = findStats((std::string)((char*)&buffer));
```

Case II is the case I need to work and has the same value as above Case I at start of function findStats but offsets for \r Are not stored for w.e reason when sString has same value at start of function.

```
    //Function that finds positioning of \r

void calc_z (std::string &s, std::vector<int> & z)
{
int len = s.size();
z.resize (len);

int l = 0, r = 0;
for (int i=1; i<len; ++i)
    if (z[i-l]+i <= r)
        z[i] = z[i-l];
    else
    {
        l = i;
        if (i > r) r = i;
        for (z[i] = r-i; r<len; ++r, ++z[i])
            if (s[r] != s[z[i]])
                break;
        --r;
    }
}


std::vector<std::string> findStats(std::string sString){
//sString is exactly the same in value for both cases of stats at this point
int offSet = 0;
int sOffsets[100] = {};

std::vector<std::string> t1;
std::string main_string = sString;
std::string substring = "\r";
std::string working_string = substring + main_string;
std::vector<int> z;
calc_z(working_string, z);

for(int i = substring.size(); i < working_string.size(); ++i){
    if(z[i] >=substring.size()){
        sOffsets[offSet] = i;
        offSet++;
    }
}
.... code ....problem occurs right above offsets are not stored for \r
}

void main()
{   
std::vector<std::string> stats;
std::string buffer[10];

    ...code...
    ...code to find string and store in buffer...



stats = findStats((std::string)((char*)&buffer));
//stats = findStats("^9dff9d[Attribute 0% Active Defense 0]\r^f2f3f2Mana: 1411 ^00ff00(+1975)\r^f2f3f2^9dff9d[Attribute 0% Active Mana 0]\r^f2f3f2^ffc000Fortify Level: 12/12\r^f2f3f2^006effIdentified Attribute: + 6% Crit Damage\rIdentified Attribute: + 6  Accuracy\r^f2f3f2^006eff^O053Sacrifice Elapse(6/8)\r^00ff00  ^O041Desollar's Shadow\rÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌL«");
for( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = stats.begin(); i != stats.end(); ++i)std::cout << *i << ' ' << std::endl;

std::cin.get();

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe shortly write what findStats should exactly do? If it really only needs to return the offsets of \r, then it looks overly complicated on first glance

Comment: What exactly is it you think `(std::string)((char*)&buffer)` does?

Comment: I accidentally left it like that because I was trying lot different things to make it work but it was originally stats = findStats((char*)buffer);

Comment: as for findStats function it does more after finding position of \r, but the rest of function is irrelevant to the problem. In case I sOffsets[offSet] has 4-5 different positions of \r while in Case II it has zero positions of \r even through sString has same exact value at start of function findStats. As for reason I am casting it into char* is because the function takes a string and my buffer is an array

Comment: @MathHelpAnswer: You said it crashes with bad alloc. You only provided partial code of `findStats()`. Without full code it won't be possible to tell why it crashes.

Comment: @MathHelpAnswer: "because the function takes a string and my buffer is an array" That's not a good enough reason. char* is not a string, and your buffer is an array of strings. No need to cast anything. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement: `(std::string)((char*)&buffer)` does not do what you think it does.

1. `std::vector` is not a simple array.
2. If you take address of `std::vector`, that won't be the address of the first element within `std::vector`.
3. YOu can't just cast `const char*` or `char*` into std::string. You can, however, construct new `std::string` using provided `const char*` or `char *` c-style string. `const char *str = asdf; std::string s = std::string(str);`.

So, to summarize:

1. If you want to pass several strings at once in `std::vector`, pass the buffer by const reference

   ```
   typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

   void test(const StringVector& v){
      for (StringVector::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
          std::cout << *i << std::endl;
   }

   ...

   StringVector strings;
   test(strings);
   ```
2. If you want to WRITE something into `std::vector`, pass it by reference:

   ```
   typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

   void test(const StringVector& out){
      out.push_back("test");
   }

   ...

   StringVector strings;
   test(strings);
   ```
3. If you want to pass a single string from, vector, just pass the element itself (by reference, const reference, or by value, depending on what you want to do with it), without casts.

   ```
   typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

   void test(const std::string& s){
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
   }

   ...

   StringVector strings;
   strings.push_back("test");
   test(strings[0]);
   ```

--edit--

IN addition to that:

```
std::vector<std::string> findStats(std::string sString){
//sString is exactly the same in value for both cases of stats at this point
int offSet = 0;
int sOffsets[100] = {};//<<here's a problem
```

Using array with fixed size in this case is a bad idea. Your array is small, and it WILL overflow on any string larger than 100 bytes, breaking/crashing your program. You can simply store results on `std::vectro<std::string>`, make vector of structs, or use `std::map`, depending on your goals.